# I want to add strings from a textfields of UITableviewCell in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have custom cell in which there are three textfields and on button tap user can add more cells. On other button tap I want to make array of textfields strings in array.

Comment: Add your custom cell class code. unless you want us to answer you with words not code.

Comment: Its just a custom cell with three textfields no code...all i have to do is make array of string from text of uitextfield in cell

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** : you'r adding 3 `UITextField` on every click on button.

You need to take `array of dictionary`

Initially array will be like this

```
arrayOfTextField = [

{
    textField1 = "",
    textField2 = "",
    textField3 = ""
}

]
```

on button click create a dictionary like below

```
dictOfTextField = {
    textField1 = "",
    textField2 = "",
    textField3 = ""
}
```

and add dictionary in arayOfTextField

```
arrayOfTextField.append(dictOfTextField)
```

Comment: text field is in tableviewcell

Comment: @MuhammadUmar How many textFields you have to add on one time button click

Comment: I have three text fields in a cell and i have to make 3 arrays each for textfield in cell.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar No do as I said above for optimisation.